# Python Selenium - best way to capture element (Xpath or CSS selector) in this case (an input box)?

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath

I am trying to scrape a website with selenium and I am using mostly xpath or CSS selector to grab elements. However I am noticing that these are dynamic (even though I read online that CSS selector shouldnt be) and I am having to re write the code often. I am fairly new to this and would like help figuring out what would be the best way to do this. Below is an example of an element that is an input box that I am trying to grab, I understand more definitive selectors like ID are more robust to use but I cant seem to find any identifiers in this case. Element below -

```
<dpm-input-number-bare><input size="1" type="text" placeholder="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"></dpm-input-number-bare>
```

This doesnt work -

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-touched")
```

Here is the higher level - its basically an input box to enter the fixed rate (the label right next to the box)

```
<div class="dpm-form-row"><dpm-input-number class="flex-6"><dpm-input-label><label>Fixed Rate</label></dpm-input-label><dpm-input-number-bare><input size="1" type="text" placeholder="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"></dpm-input-number-bare></dpm-input-number><div class="flex-6"></div></div>
```

Comment: How about `dpm-input-number-bare > input` ? You might have to go up more and find some text

Comment: Please post more of your HTML data. It will be needed to find a good anchor point.

Comment: You can try `.find_element_by_css_selector("input.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-touched")`

Comment: @frianH it didnt work :(

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-touched"}

Comment: @E.Wiest added more details

Answer (score 1):

You can locate the element with the following XPath :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"][../preceding-sibling::dpm-input-label[1]/label[.="Fixed Rate"]]')
```

We use the `label` element as an anchor point. Get the `input` element which fulfill the following condition : the first `preceding-sibling` of its `parent` has a `label` child which contains the term "Fixed Rate".

If needed, add an expected condition (element can receive the click). Assuming you want to send "12" in the input box :

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"][../preceding-sibling::dpm-input-label[1]/label[.="Fixed Rate"]]'))).send_keys("12")
```

Imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**EDIT** : Other XPath alternatives :

3 XPath using `following-sibling` axis :

```
//dpm-input-label[label[.="Fixed Rate"]]/following-sibling::dpm-input-number-bare[1]/input
//dpm-input-label[label[contains(.,"Fixed Rate")]]/following-sibling::dpm-input-number-bare[1]/input
//dpm-input-label[contains(.,"Fixed Rate")]/following-sibling::dpm-input-number-bare[1]/input
```

3 XPath using `preceding-sibling` axis and multiple `contains` for the `input` element :

```
//input[contains(@class,"ng-pristine") and contains(@class,"ng-valid") and contains(@class,"ng-touched")][../preceding-sibling::dpm-input-label[1]/label[.="Fixed Rate"]]
//input[contains(@class,"ng-pristine") and contains(@class,"ng-valid") and contains(@class,"ng-touched")][../preceding-sibling::dpm-input-label[1]/label[contains(.,"Fixed Rate")]]
//input[contains(@class,"ng-pristine") and contains(@class,"ng-valid") and contains(@class,"ng-touched")][../preceding-sibling::dpm-input-label[1][contains(.,"Fixed Rate")]]
```

4 XPath using `preceding` axis :

```
//input[@class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"][preceding::label[1][.="Fixed Rate"]]
//input[@class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"][preceding::label[1][contains(.,"Fixed Rate")]]
//input[contains(@class,"ng-pristine") and contains(@class,"ng-valid") and contains(@class,"ng-touched")][preceding::label[1][.="Fixed Rate"]]
//input[contains(@class,"ng-pristine") and contains(@class,"ng-valid") and contains(@class,"ng-touched")][preceding::label[1][contains(.,"Fixed Rate")]]
```

Comment: Actually didnt work, but I am quite sure its just a syntax issue so repeating the DOM and the code below -

<div class="dpm-form-row ng-star-inserted">
<dpm-input-number class="flex-6">
<dpm-input-label>
<label>Fixed Rate</label>
</dpm-input-label>
<dpm-input-number-bare>
<input size="1" type="text" placeholder="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
</dpm-input-number-bare>
</dpm-input-number>
<div class="flex-6">
</div>
</div>

Comment: XPath looks fine to me. Post has been edited with 10 other expressions. Post the relevant error code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="text"]')
```

However, if there are more than one elements by the same XPath, it might raise an error.

Comment: I am afraid that doesnt work since there are multiple input boxes on the page :(

Answer (score 0):

how about finding the element using its class

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched')
```

Comment: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

Answer (score 0):

Try following approach with xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dpm-form-row' and contains(., 'Fixed Rate')]//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']")
```