# Find element using parent/sibling in python selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am using selenium in python to scrape a web page designed with angular js and hence has no robust identifiers for elements such as id etc. I am completely reliant on CSS selectors (which are dynamic) and xpaths.

I have the following code -

```
<div class="dpm-form-row ng-star-inserted">
<dpm-input-number class="flex-6">
<dpm-input-label>
<label>Fixed Rate</label>
</dpm-input-label>
<dpm-input-number-bare>
<input size="1" type="text" placeholder="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
</dpm-input-number-bare>
</dpm-input-number>
<div class="flex-6">
</div>
</div>
```

It's basically a label called "Fixed Rate" followed by an input text box. Its that box I am trying to grab.

I have managed to get the label using the following code, I am having trouble using the parent/sibling logic to get the box -

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Fixed Rate")]')
```

Comment: You can copy the xpath of input element by inspecting element.

Comment: doesnt the browser renders jsx or whatever angular uses to html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repost from your [preceding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63062499/python-selenium-best-way-to-capture-element-xpath-or-css-selector-in-this-ca/63075706?noredirect=1#comment111563347_63075706) question. Original solution :

```
//input[@class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"][../preceding-sibling::dpm-input-label[1]/label[.="Fixed Rate"]]
```

3 XPath using `following-sibling` axis :

```
//dpm-input-label[label[.="Fixed Rate"]]/following-sibling::dpm-input-number-bare[1]/input
//dpm-input-label[label[contains(.,"Fixed Rate")]]/following-sibling::dpm-input-number-bare[1]/input
//dpm-input-label[contains(.,"Fixed Rate")]/following-sibling::dpm-input-number-bare[1]/input
```

3 XPath using `preceding-sibling` axis and multiple `contains` for the `input` element :

```
//input[contains(@class,"ng-pristine") and contains(@class,"ng-valid") and contains(@class,"ng-touched")][../preceding-sibling::dpm-input-label[1]/label[.="Fixed Rate"]]
//input[contains(@class,"ng-pristine") and contains(@class,"ng-valid") and contains(@class,"ng-touched")][../preceding-sibling::dpm-input-label[1]/label[contains(.,"Fixed Rate")]]
//input[contains(@class,"ng-pristine") and contains(@class,"ng-valid") and contains(@class,"ng-touched")][../preceding-sibling::dpm-input-label[1][contains(.,"Fixed Rate")]]
```

4 XPath using `preceding` axis :

```
//input[@class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"][preceding::label[1][.="Fixed Rate"]]
//input[@class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"][preceding::label[1][contains(.,"Fixed Rate")]]
//input[contains(@class,"ng-pristine") and contains(@class,"ng-valid") and contains(@class,"ng-touched")][preceding::label[1][.="Fixed Rate"]]
//input[contains(@class,"ng-pristine") and contains(@class,"ng-valid") and contains(@class,"ng-touched")][preceding::label[1][contains(.,"Fixed Rate")]]
```

Comment: Thank you vm, for some reason the original solution wasnt working, thanks a lot again

Comment: Your answers are really so helpful specially the options you provide within your answers.